# HttpServletResponse.resetBuffer() doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

In Google's Appengine with Java, the servlet:

```
@Override protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Writer w=resp.getWriter();
    w.write("a");
    resp.resetBuffer();
    w=resp.getWriter();
    w.write("b");
}
```

gives "ab" in the response, in the development server. I was expected just "b", from reading Servlet Spec 2.5.

What is wrong?

I'm reading the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/requests.

I tried resp.setBufferSize(8192) and then getBufferSize() but just got 1.

appengine version: 1.9.34, java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal", ubuntu 14.10

Comment: I've opened a couple of bugs with Google: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12906 https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12907 Thanks, Google!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the Java Servlet Specification (Version 3.0) says:

> "The `reset` method clears data in the buffer when the response is not
>   committed. Headers and status codes set by the servlet prior to the
>   reset call must be cleared as well. The `resetBuffer` method clears
>   content in the buffer if the response is not committed without
>   clearing the headers and status code.
>
> If the response is committed and the `reset` or `resetBuffer` method is
>   called, an `IllegalStateException` must be thrown. The response and its
>   associated buffer will be unchanged."

Facially, that says that `resetBuffer` should either clear out the `"a"` or throw an exception.

I guess, you could make the argument that the characters are buffered in the `Writer` not the response buffer, but the Servlet spec doesn't make any such distinction.  Furthermore, such an interpretation of the spec would render `resetBuffer` effectively useless.

If Google AppEngine is really behaving the way you say, I'd call that a bug.

Comment: A bug in something so basic in appengine? Hard to believe, there must be something else.

Comment: Perhaps GAE isn't really behaving that way then.